# Convert hours:minutes to minutes:seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I have a bunch of running times that I've pasted into excel, such as 12:31 (twelve minutes, thirty one seconds).

However, even though the cell itself shows `12:31`, Excel automatically reads it as `12:31:00 PM`. If I try to multiply it by two, it returns `1:02` instead of `25:02`.

What's the easiest way to convert this time to minutes:seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores time as fractions of a day

- When you entered `12:31`, Excel interprets that as 12 hours 31 minutes and stores it as `0.521527778`
- You can convert that value to minutes:seconds by dividing the entire value by 60
- You can then display it as minutes:seconds with the format:  `[m]:ss`
  *the brackets around the `m` keep it from rolling over when it gets to 60*

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was extracting the values from the cell:

`=HOUR(A1)/24/60+MINUTE(A1)/24/60/60`

This takes the original "hour" and converts it to minutes, then adds the original "minutes" converted as seconds.

Comment: `=A1/60` will do it also.